# Java RSASSA-PKCS1 howto

Tags: java, rsa, ssa

Can anybody tell me how to generate signature for `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1.5` in Java?

I, actually, want to know how do I with `java.security.Signature` class.

Do I have to use any 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sun JCE supports PKCS#1 signature. This is all you have to do,

```
Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
signer.initSign(privateKey);
signer.update(message);
byte[] signature = signer.sign();
```

Comment: or `"SHA256withRSA"` or some other hashing, depending on your case.